# Why Parent class Reference variable can point to Derived class object in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the advantage in using Parent Class Reference variable point to Derived class or child class object.

```
public abstract Class Customer
{
public abstract void Print();
}
public class Program :Customer
{
public override void Print()
{
Console.WriteLine("Print");
} 

}
public Static void main()
{
Customer C= new Program();
C.Print();
}
```

What is the Benefit of doing this

```
   Customer C= new Program();
   C.Print();
```

Or what is the difference

```
   Program P = new Program();
   P.Print();
```

Since both giving the  same Result.

Comment: What if you had a base class of `Fruit`, having a property named `Color`. You have derived classes, `Banana`, `Apple`, and `Orange`. If you had an instance of each derived class in a `List`, how would you print the color of each fruit without knowing the actual derived type? In other words, given a `List<Fruit>`, what do you get by looping over that list and assigning to a variable `Fruit fruitInstance`?

Comment: Lookup polymorphism